# I have used the A-frame JS for 360 view image but i can't able to find the default loader

Tags: aframe

I have using A-frame JS for 360 view.but when 360 image shows before that loader also will show then only image will come..the loader come with te default background-color..i want to remove the default bg color and need transparent